# Apache Commons Net 3.3 slow download times

Tags: java, performance, apache-commons-net

Using FTPClient to retrieve files takes at least 4 times longer than simply fetching file with lftp.

What did I do wrong? Here's my setup

```
client.connect(Address);

client.login(Login, Pass);
//client.setConnectTimeout(keepAliveTime);
//client.setControlKeepAliveTimeout(keepAliveTime);
//client.setControlKeepAliveReplyTimeout(keepAliveTime);
//client.setBufferSize(1024*1024*10);
//client.enterLocalPassiveMode(); //any profit?
client.changeWorkingDirectory(ftpDirectory);
client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
client.retrieveFile(filename,new FileOutputStream(filepath));
```

Edit:
          I tried FTPClient#retrieveFileStream(String filename) method instead and the file downloads as fast as through 'lftp' , but the program then hangs on completePendingCommand() , which is necessary.

Edit 2:  Ftp4j library is twice as fast as commons-net , but still half slower than my connection speed.

Are there really no good java ftp libraries?

Comment: Any solution for this. I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @ypriverol No, sorry. I opted to use python back then instead.

Comment: is python faster. I make my ftpclient object final forcing to use only one object. but is two slow.

Comment: A python ftp library was faster for me in this particular case.